# In Java, Why is null allowed in some collection implementation and not in others?

Tags: java, collections

In Java, In general, some collection implementations allow null elements and some don't.
Has it something to do with garbage collection?

Comment: Because that's the way they designed it. You would have to ask the designers. Anything you get here will be guesswork. Not constructive.

Comment: Since you didn't specify the collections you're talking about, I'm guessing you were referring `HashTable` (which doesn't allow nullable values) vs. `HashMap` (which does). The only thing is, `HashTable` is not part of the Java Collections - it's considered legacy code!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a broad sense I think it's just basically up to the implementation to decide whether `null` can be **a valid element** of the collection ('logically') or not. I really doubt there's more to it although I could be proven wrong.

Relevant bits from [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html):

> Some collection implementations have restrictions on the elements that
>   they may contain. For example, some implementations prohibit null
>   elements, and some have restrictions on the types of their elements.
>   Attempting to add an ineligible element throws an unchecked exception,
>   typically NullPointerException or ClassCastException. Attempting to
>   query the presence of an ineligible element may throw an exception, or
>   it may simply return false; some implementations will exhibit the
>   former behavior and some will exhibit the latter. More generally,
>   attempting an operation on an ineligible element whose completion
>   would not result in the insertion of an ineligible element into the
>   collection may throw an exception or it may succeed, at the option of
>   the implementation. Such exceptions are marked as "optional" in the
>   specification for this interface.

Comment: +1 for basically "it's up to the implementation" (and the implementors).  For example, Guava chooses to reject null for many of its collection implementations just because the Guava team believes that's preferable for most users.

Comment: @LouisWasserman your profile says Chicago but I could swear I saw you last week on the meetup... :P

Comment: That's because I started work at MTV three weeks ago.